# Downloading a file: works on Windows, doesn't work in Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, download

I'm using the following code to download a file from the internet, updating a progress bar to show how much of the file is downloaded, and to allow the user to cancel the download:

```
final Path tempDirectory = jesterDirectory.resolve( "temp" );
final Path updateFile = tempDirectory.resolve( "update.zip" );

updater.statusArea.append( "Fetch:\t\tDownloading update.zip from " + targetURL + "\n");
URL url = new URL( targetURL );
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int filesize = connection.getContentLength();
float totalDataRead = 0;
java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream( connection.getInputStream() );
java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream( updateFile.toString() );
java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream( fos, 1024 );
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int i = 0;
while ( ( i = in.read ( data, 0, 1024 ) ) >= 0 ) {

    if ( updater.cancelUpdate ) {
        updater.statusArea.append( "Fetch:\t\tCanceled\n");
        unblock();
        bout.close();
        in.close();
        return;
    }
    totalDataRead = totalDataRead+i;
    bout.write( data, 0, i );
    float Percent = ( totalDataRead * 100 )/filesize;
    updater.progressBar.setValue( (int)Percent );
}   
bout.close();
in.close();
updater.statusArea.append( "Fetch:\t\tSuccess!\n");
```

It works perfectly on Windows. On Linux, it seems to download successfully, but the file is corrupted, unreadable.

Any idea what's causing the difference?

Comment: How is it corrupted?

Comment: I figured out the problem: targetURL points to a .tar.gz when I'm on a linux machine. I need to check for that and adapt this code to work for both zips and tar.gzs.  Sorry for the unanswerable question!